# Python Pillow's Image.Split is not returning RBG, but images are all in a grayscale, what would cause this?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am working on a course about Pillow. There is no information on how to do the assignment, so I am lost.

Reading the Pillow documentation is not helpful, so I am unsure why an image converted to RBG is not being split into RBG, but into grayscale.

```
help(Image.Image.split)
```

Looking at [Python For Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-image-split-method/#:%7E:text=image%20editing%20capabilities.-,Image.,red%2C%20green%2C%20blue).

they are also showing gray images instead of red, blue, and green images.
If the .split() is supposed to split it into the RBG tuple, why are the images only being shown in gray?

```
#Code snippet from Python for Geeks
im1 = Image.Image.split(image) 
im1[0].show()
display(im1[0])
display(im1[1])
display(im1[2])
```

Answer (score 2):

When you split a 3-channel RGB image, it becomes 3 separate, single-channel images. Single-channel images are generally considered greyscale. So you get 3 greyscale images.

Start instead with:

```
from PIL import Image

R, G, B = Image.split(...)
```

Now, if you want the Red channel to be shown in red, you'll need to make it back into a colour image, by creating an empty (zeroed out) Green and Blue channel, and merging back to colour:

```
empty = Image.new("L", SIZE, "black")
RedChannelInRed = Image.merge("RGB", (R, empty, empty))

GreenChannelInGreen = Image.merge("RGB", (empty, G, empty))

BlueChannelInBlue = Image.merge("RGB", (empty, empty, B))
```

---

Alternatively, rather than pulling the image apart into its constituent channels, and then re-assembling it, you could apply a colour matrix to [convert](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert) the image *"in-situ"* like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# Open image
im = Image.open('image.jpg')

# Define color matrix to retain red channel unchanged and zero the green and blue channels
# This says:
# New red   = 1*old red + 0*old green + 0*old blue + 0offset
# New green = 0*old red + 0*old green + 0*old blue + 0offset
# New blue  = 0*old red + 0*old green + 0*old blue + 0offset
RedMatrix = ( 1, 0, 0, 0,
              0, 0, 0, 0,
              0, 0, 0, 0)

Red = im.convert('RGB', RedMatrix)
Red.save('result-R.jpg')

# Do the same thing for Green channel
GreenMatrix = ( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Green = im.convert('RGB', GreenMatrix)
Green.save('result-G.jpg')

# Do the same thing for Blue channel
BlueMatrix = ( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
Blue = im.convert('RGB', BlueMatrix)
Blue.save('result-B.jpg')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The "L" and SIZE may I ask where that came from? I did not see it in the docs. Do I create a variable for size and L? Thank you again. This Coursera assignment gave no instructions on how to complete it, and I am trying to understand a completed one I found because I will not turn in something I did not do or understand, so I truly appreciate your help.

Comment: The SIZE is for you to fill in - I don't know what size your image is. The "L" means a single channel image - it stands for "Luminance" or "Lightness" and just means *"grey"*.

Comment: Thank you. I keep getting a size mismatch.
image=Image.open("readonly/msi_recruitment.gif")
image=image.convert('RGB')

empty = Image.new(mode = "L", size = (100, 100))
R, G, B = Image.Image.split(image)
RedChannelInRed = Image.merge("RGB", (R, empty, empty))
GreenChannelInGreen = Image.merge("RGB", (empty, G, empty))
BlueChannelInBlue = Image.merge("RGB", (empty, empty, B))

Comment: If I do not use Image.Image I get another error saying that Image has no attribute image, I believe.

Comment: That's because you need to do `from PIL import Image` at the top.